# Issue in android phone contacts to post php server

Tags: android, json, android-contacts

Currently I am working with android contacts, I am able to get all contacts and display it in list view, but my issues is when I post the **json array** to server it's not syncing to the server.

here is my code

```
try {
    //constants
    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.2.106/contacts_syn_api/jsoncontacts.php");

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject contactObj = new JSONObject();
    if (StoreContacts != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < StoreContacts.size(); i++) {
            String[] splitedValue = StoreContacts.get(i).split(",");
            for (int j = 0; j < splitedValue.length; j++) {
                String[] splitedValue1 = splitedValue[j].split("~");
                for (int k = 0; k < splitedValue1.length; k++) {
                    String[] separated = splitedValue1[k].split(":");
                    name = separated[0];
                    phonenumber = separated[1];
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObj.put("name", name);
                    jsonObj.put("phoneNo", phonenumber);
                    jsonObj.put("tag", tag_status);
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
                }
            }
        }

        contactObj.put("Conatct", jsonArray);
    }
    String message1 = contactObj.toString();
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout( 10000 /*milliseconds*/ );
    conn.setConnectTimeout( 15000 /* milliseconds */ );
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);

    os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    os.write(bytes);
    String s = new String(bytes);
    System.out.println(s);
    //clean up
    os.flush();
```

Comment: Show your code and explain what issue you are facing..

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: `message.getBytes()` should be `message1.getBytes()`?